# What went wrong in finding kernel of $f(x,y)\mapsto f(t^2,t)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Suppose that $F$ is a field and let $F[x,y]$ be a polynomial ring. The map $\phi: F[x,y]\to F[y]$, defined by $\phi(f(x,y))=f(y^2,y)$ has kernel $(y^2-x)$. I want to prove that the kernel is as the statement says.

It is clear that $\phi(x)=y^2, \phi(y)=y.$

For any $u(x,y)\in (y^2-x)$, there exists a $v(x,y)\in F[x,y]$ such that $u(x,y)=v(x,y)(y^2-x)$. $\phi(v(x,y)) =\phi(v(x,y))\phi(x^2-y)=\phi(v(x,y))(\phi(y^2)-\phi(x))=\phi(v(x,y))(y^2-y^2)=0\implies (y^2-x)\subset \ker\phi . \tag 1$

**Conversely** for any $p(x,y)\in \ker\phi$, $p(x,y)=a_n(x)y^n+a_{n-1}(x)y^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1(x)y+a_0(x)$, where $a_j(x)\in F[x]$.

So $\phi(p(x,y))=a_n(y^2)y^n+a_{n-1}(y^2)y^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1(y^2)y+a_0(y^2)=0$.

From here, I think that by fundamental theorem of algebra, $a_j$'s are zero polynomials over $F$. It follows that $p(x,y)=0\in (x^2-y)\implies \ker \phi\subset (x^2-y). \tag 2$

By $(1)$ and $(2)$ the result follows.

My question: 'Conversely' part actually proves a stronger statement, i.e., $\ker \phi=\{0\}$, which makes me realise that there is something wrong in my proof above. But I couldn't pinpoint the error in it. Please help me fix the proof. Thanks.

Comment: How exactly do you apply fundamental theorem of algebra here? What I understand by that theorem is that complex numbers are algebraically closed. You are not even dealing with complex numbers.

Comment: @xyzzyz: You're right, thanks. It's not given that $F$ is algebraically closed. Then how would you suggest I should proceed from there?

Comment: One way would be to consider that $F[x,y]=F[y][x]$, and note that $p(x)$ (with coefficients in $F[y]$) being in the kernel means that $y^2$ is a root of $p(x)$.

Comment: @MorA. That makes sense. Thank you so much. Somehow I missed that. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the converse direction, note that $F[x,y]=F[y][x]$, so if $p(x)$ (with coefficients in $F[y]$) is in the kernel of $\phi$ then $y^2$ is a root of $p(x)$, therefore $(x-y^2)$ is a factor of $p(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $p(x, y) = y^2 - x$. Then, $a_2(x) = 1$, $a_0(x) = -x$, and all other are $a_i$ are zero polynomials. Then, $\phi(p) = a_2(y^2)y^2 + a_0(y^2) = y^2 - y^2 = 0$, but, nevertheless, $a_0$ and $a_2$ are not zero polynomials.